# Найти обьект в базе, столбец которого формата json и этот json имеет пустой массив

Tags: sql, json, база-данных, postgresql

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, мне нужно найти в PostgreSQL базе все записи, у которых в столбце, формата JSON, есть JSON с пустым массивом
Например таблица Item имеет столбец source, этот столбец формата JSON, в этом JSON есть разные данные, также есть массив с названием data. Нужно найти все записи в табличке Item у которых массив data пустой, подскажите пожалуйста какой будет запрос?

Comment: Структура JSON объекта определена?  Или требуется найти поле с пустым массивом на любом уровне вложенности?

Comment: В данном примере определена, вот такая структура {
   "id":"111111",
   "type":"111111",
   "data":[ ],
   "length",
............
......
...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поле `source` имеет тип `jsonb`, то запрос для PostgreSQL может выглядеть так:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE source->'data' = '[]'::jsonb;
```

---

Вопрос на основном сайте: [How to query for empty array in JSONB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450606/)

Comment: выводит пустой результат, думаю возможно просто таких данных в таблице может не быть. Подскажите пожалуйста, если например в массиве data несколько значений у его поля tier,
 вот например массив data ["tier1": value, "tier2": value, и так далее, какой запрос будет если я хочу получить item со значением 500 например, tier1 поля, массива data?

Comment: Это тогда не массив получается, а мапа/словарь/объект.  Массив выглядел бы `[{"tier": "value1"}, {"tier": "value2"}]` (один ключ для разных элементов массива).  В мапе искать можно так: `... WHERE source->'data'->>'tier1' = 500`

Comment: И если возникает новый вопрос, лучше его задать отдельно.